# Crashing in StreamWithExternalResource with a filename that has accents

Tags: file, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, non-ascii-characters

I have to read an image in the Pictures folder that has accents (e.g "éleá"). This name is connected with a database that has also accents. I am using those resources from a client and don't know if I can change both the database and the file name.

I have sucessfully load images without accents using this code:

```
IRandomAccessStream stream = StreamWithExternalResource(resourcePath).Result;

BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

image.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Is it possible to read files that have the filename with accents in windows metro/store apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for naming files can be found in this MSDN article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

There should not be any problem with accents, such as `áéíóú`, but you will encounter problems using reserved characters, such as `<>|\/`.

What I would try is hardcoding resourcePath using a constant filename and make sure that nothing odd comes from the database. Another test would be converting the long filename into a short filename (8.3 MS-DOS format) using the `GetShortPathName` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The problem was in the database. The database came with an extra char (from OSX). If I delete that char the "é" it turns into an "e".